# Is SQLite suitable for a forum?

Tags: sqlite, forum

I know SQLite can manage websites. But is SQLite suitable for an active forum? Or should this role be reserved for MySQL/PostgreSQL/Firbird etc?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't be fooled by its name. That's all I can advise.

Comment: @BoltClock's a Unicorn - What do you mean by this? Don't underestimate the "lite" part? or Don't overestimate it by comparing it to MySQL/PostgreSQL etc? :P

Comment: Don't underestimate the "lite" part :)

Answer (score 3):

From the SQLite website: http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html

> **Websites**
>
> SQLite usually will work great as the database engine for low to medium traffic websites (which is to say, 99.9% of all websites). The amount of web traffic that SQLite can handle depends, of course, on how heavily the website uses its database. Generally speaking, any site that gets fewer than 100K hits/day should work fine with SQLite. The 100K hits/day figure is a conservative estimate, not a hard upper bound. SQLite has been demonstrated to work with 10 times that amount of traffic.

Answer (score -2):

SQLite was designed as a single connection, local database. It isn't a tool for managing databases.

AFAIK, it still doesn't support encryption out of the box. Dr Hipp sells an encryption solution for that, and since its public domain you can find any number of products that have tacked on network support.

It is not suitable for an active forum out of the box. It *can* certainly be made to work as a database for an active forum, however there are many free and not free databases that were built to scale, support encryption natively and more. There isn't any reason to saddle yourself with SQLite's limitations.

Comment: I didn't say it wasn't able to use concurrent connections, did I? WAL solves the multi-user problem but it isn't ideal.